# Periodic Tasks in C# without the use of ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Is there a way to execute a periodic task/thread in C# without the using of a thread pool (this is one of the main requirements I have).

The expected scenario is as the following:

1. The periodic thread blocks/waits for a timer event (from the system).
2. The system notifies the thread when the timer expires.
3. The thread executes some code.
4. The thread blocks/waits for the next timer event from the system (note that if the thread missed one or more timer events, this is ok).

The closest thing I found to this is the `System.Forms.Timer`, but the issue is that its accuracy is limited to 55ms which is not enough for me.

The `System.Timers.Timer` seems to be able to handle this via the `SynchronizingObject` property. However, I'm not really sure how to implement a `ISynchronizeInvoke` according to the above scenario. All of the code samples I found for implementing `ISynchronizeInvoke` seem too complicated for handling such a simple scenario.

Is there a way to easily implement this feature in C# as in the above scenario (without using threadpools) and more accurate than the `System.Forms.Timer`?

Comment: What level of accuracy do you need?

Comment: The shortest period I will deal with is about 10ms.

Comment: What are you doing that requires a action every 10ms, there may be better solutions. Please give us the big picture of what you are trying to do to prevent a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Mainly monitoring/polling passive devices.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19341345/edit) and show exactly how you are monitoring the device, what interface does it use, is there a library or are you doing something like talking to it over a COM port? Give us more details and someone who has may have worked with the same device before could give you some advice from what they have learned when they tried to solve the same problem as you.

Answer (score 4):

Windows timers have a default resolution of 15.6 ms, from their [documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/0/2/3027D574-C433-412A-A8B6-5E0A75D5B237/Timer-Resolution.docx):

> The default system-wide timer resolution in Windows is 15.6 ms, which
>   means that every 15.6 ms the operating system receives a clock
>   interrupt from the system timer hardware. When the clock interrupt
>   fires, Windows updates the timer tick count and checks whether a
>   scheduled timer object has expired. Some applications require that
>   timer expiration is serviced more frequently than once every 15.6 ms.

They also state:

> Applications can call timeBeginPeriod to increase the timer
>   resolution. The maximum resolution of 1 ms is used to support
>   graphical animations, audio playback, or video playback. This not only
>   increases the timer resolution for the application to 1 ms, but also
>   affects the global system timer resolution, because Windows uses at
>   least the highest resolution (that is, the lowest interval) that any
>   application requests. Therefore, if only one application requests a
>   timer resolution of 1 ms, the system timer sets the interval (also
>   called the “system timer tick”) to at least 1 ms. For more
>   information, see “timeBeginPeriod Function” on the MSDN® website.

So if you really need high resolution timers, you can use the [timeBeginPeriod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call to affect the global system timer, but know that it will affect the batter life/power consuption of the device on which it is working.

Also, there are the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) calls that can be used to get lower levels of precision in .net, like in this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571289/Obtaining-Microsecond-Precision-in-NET

Answer (score 2):

[Multimedia Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will provide you with the highest resolution of all timers. If you really and truly need 10ms or less resolution, that will be the only way to go.

If you find that you do not need the resolution provided by Multimedia Timers, you will find that [Waitable Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will give you the ability to code a loop that waits for a timer to expire within a single thread.

You also may choose [Timer Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which provide a large number of timers without the resource overhead of the other timers, but by default uses the system thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply sleep your thread?

```
int msecSleepTime = 25;  // number of milliseconds to sleep
Thread.Sleep(msecSleepTime);  // sleep the current thread for the given number of milliseconds
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy my needs. Assume that I need to run the thread every 25ms, and my code execution takes about 10ms. This means that the next time I execute the code will be after 35ms rather than 25ms!

Comment: You could record how long the code took to execute and do the math and figure out how many ms you need to sleep each time

Comment: Maybe I'll resort to this if I have no other/better options.

Comment: It's not a bad option - it's self-contained, uses no other threads to run the timing and will work anywhere in the calling function/s without resorting to event-driven state-machines.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest response from `System.Timers.Timer` on my system w/o reconfiguring the system's timer is ~16 ms.  Set your `Timer.Interval` value to `(int)( target interval / 16 ) * 16` then have the thread sleep for the remaining duration (and if you really need better accuracy, an interpreted language such as C# is not the correct choice):

```
class Program
{
    private static Timer _timer = new Timer();
    private static DateTime _last = DateTime.Now;
    private const int IntendedInterval = 25;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.Interval = (int)(IntendedInterval / 16) * 16;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var duration = now - _last;

        var sleep = IntendedInterval - duration.TotalMilliseconds;

        if (0 < sleep )
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(( int )sleep);
        }

        _timer.Start();

        now = DateTime.Now;
        duration = now - _last;
        _last = now;

        Console.WriteLine(duration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
    }
}
```